# Extract specific values from XML configuration

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmlstarlet

Input XML looks like several blocks of:

```
<Parties>
  <Party compid="CUST1" side="1">
                <Connections>
                    <SocketConnection listenport="9029" />
                </Connections>
   </Party>
</Parties>
```

My goal is to extract to each customer his specific params like:
compid;listenport

By now I can get all customers using

```
xmlstarlet fo -D config.xml | xmlstarlet select -T -t -m '//Parties/Party' -v '@compid' -nl
```

Next step would be a loop for each customer to get his listenport, but

```
xmlstarlet fo -D config.xml | xmlstarlet select -T -t -m '//Parties/Party[@compid="CUST1"]' -v 'Connections/SocketConnection/@listenport'
```

or any other try returns nothing.
Am I missing something at filtering using `[@value=string]`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example and `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet select --text --template --match '//Parties/Party' --value-of \
  'concat(@compid,";",Connections/SocketConnection/@listenport)' -n config.xml
```

Output:

```
CUST1;9029
```

See: `xmlstarlet select --help`